# How can I determine the changes I've made to my ISPF Edit data before I save it?

Tags: mainframe, zos, ispf

I've been editing and testing JCL for sometime without doing a save under ISPF Edit. I changed something and the JCL now fails (JCL Error). I know I can look in the jobs sysout using SDSF but is there a way to find out what I changed while in ISPF Edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2 - Or if you avoid PDSE's like I do, the CBT Tape PDS command has the RESTORE function where you can often find the previous member.

Comment: That only works if the PDS (not a PDSE) has not been compressed. :)

Comment: True, but in my experience compression was typically done only as a reaction after a PDS ran out of space.  So that was rarely a problem when hunting for a previous member.

Comment: unless storage management ran a nightly compress and reorg of volumes and/or dfsmshsm migrated the dataset and then the recall was compresssed - you can't win sometimes.

Comment: Why the avoidance of PDSEs?

Comment: @Steve - It's personal

Comment: @TomBrennan They got a bad rep in the early 2000's, to the extent we were told not to use then when I was at Citigroup, but since IBM started shipping z/OS with them, they seem ok. Also I assume you are the author of the 3270 emulator, Vista?

Comment: @Steve Yes, that's me!

Answer (score 4):

There are two answers:

1. Providing you have **not** issued a Edit SAVE command then you can enter `compare * x` to see the records removed, added, or changed. If you have performed a SAVE then this will not be possible.
2. If, and I highly recommended, you are using PDSE member generations **and** using the open-source PDSEGEN tool (https://github.com/lbdyck/pdsedgen), then you can issue a `compare -n` where 'n' is a previous generation.

hope this helps